# C++: vector<string> to char**

Tags: c++, vector

I am converting my app to be able to be used as a library. For this purpose, I want to offer the possibility to pass a vector of strings to the library's default run routine.

The problem I am running into, is actually creating the `char**`. This is my current implementation, commented out in the source since it isn't working:

```
IceTea* IceTea::setupCli(vector<string> strings) {
    int argc=strings.size(), i=0;
    char* argv[argc];
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for(it=strings.begin(); it != strings.end(); ++it) {
        argv[i++] = (char*)it->c_str();
    }

    // Pass the char** to the original method.
    return this->setupCli(argc, argv);
}
```

The error I get:

```
src/IceTea.cpp:132:18: error: no matching member function for call to 'setupCli'
    return this->setupCli(argc, argv);
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
src/IceTea.h:44:13: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char *[argc]' to 'const char **' for 2nd argument
    IceTea* setupCli(int, const char**);
            ^
src/IceTea.cpp:124:17: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'strings', but 2 arguments were provided
IceTea* IceTea::setupCli(vector<string> strings) {
```

Comment: _`char* argv[argc];`_ VLA's aren't standard c++

Comment: How did you declare the 2nd `setupCli()` function?

Comment: Can you show the two-args function signature?

Comment: just declare `const char* argv[argc];`  and you're done.

Comment: `(char*)it->c_str()` is dangerous. Casting away the the `const` is not recommended.

Comment: Why not make `setupCli` accept a `const std::vector<std::string>&` as its single parameter?

Comment: can you shos us the definition of `IceTea::setup(int, char **)` that you are calling in your return statement ?

Comment: Why not converting simply with `const char** argv = new const char*[argc]; transform (strings.begin(), strings.end(), &argv[0], [](const string &s)->const char* {return s.c_str();});`  ?

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid you cannot convert a `vector<string>` to `char**` in constant time. A `vector<string>` can be converted to `string*` pretty easily, and `string` can be converted to `char*` pretty easily, but vector cannot be converted to `char**`. Actually, this is a problem very similar to why an `int[10][20]` cannot be trivially converted to an `int**`.

Now, if you absolutely have to do this, then

```
vector<char*> pointerVec(strings.size());
for(unsigned i = 0; i < strings.size(); ++i)
{
    pointerVec[i] = strings[i].data();
} //you can use transform instead of this loop
char** result = pointerVec.data();
```

The main problem with your code is that you're using `c_str` which returns a `const char *`. Note that I'm using the `data()` member function instead, which returns the non-const pointer. Another difference between your attempt and my suggestion is that you're using an array of a length which is not a constant expression. That is illegal in standard C++. I used a vector instead and later converted it to a pointer with the same `data()` function.

Comment: I am getting an error as 'Error: data is not a member of std::vector<char*>' for the last line on the Solaris machine